# Single space but double space for paragraph separation

Tags: paragraphs, line-spacing, setspace

a bit new to LaTeX

My paper is in single-space via `\usepackage{setspace}\singlespacing` 
but I have to use double-space for paragraph separation

Any way to do this without having to get rid of `\singlespacing`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use the [parskip](https://ctan.org/pkg/parskip) package:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=\glueexpr \baselineskip + 0pt plus 2pt\relax]{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

The default value for the `skip` option of `parskip` is `0.5\baselineskip` with the addition of `2pt` of stretchability. The example above increases this by `0.5\baselineskip` to match your stated requirement.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not need change spacing, remove `setspace` package and `\signglespacing` command. Instead play with `parskip`, like in this example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```